# User Control SELECTOR - Problem with Boxview When setting CornerRadius at runtime (Solved by using Frame - Why?)

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, binding, user-controls

I made an selector component which look like this :
[image]
I like it because I can assign commands individually for each item :

```
public ICommand[] SelectorCommands => _SelectorCommands ??= new ICommand[2]{
    new Command(StartLogs),
    new Command(StopLogs)
};
private ICommand[] _SelectorCommands;
```

My problem is to dynimically set the radius property according to the Height of the control. My solution works in UWP but doesn't work in Android, with the same code :
[image]

I can't find Why. I made 2 attempts to handle the adaptative CornerRadius (Look in the code of the component). The first attempt by overriding OnPropertyChanged. It works in UWP but not in Android.  In Android, the boxes for background are not rendered at start. But correctly as soon as you click once on an item.

The second attempt I tried is to use a binding (look at the 2 lines to uncomment in the code of the component). This doesn't work in Android (same result than with option 1 and crash in UWP ;-).

Can anybody have a look and find out a working solution ? Feel free to make comment on the component and resuse it ... or share a better (and as easy to use) working one.

I made a public repo here :  https://github.com/BelightWavre/TestBLSelector. For those who do not want to use GitHub, just add those lines in the MainPage.xaml of a blank Xamarin.Forms project:

```
<component:BLSelector HorizontalOptions = "Start"
        FontSize="16"
        TextColor="Black"
        ItemBackgroundColor="LightGray"
        SelectedItemBackgroundColor="Green"
        Margin="5">
    <component:BLSelector.Labels>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
            <x:String>Item1</x:String>
            <x:String>Item2</x:String>
        </x:Array>
    </component:BLSelector.Labels>
</component:BLSelector>
```

Plus the namespace in the header :

```
 xmlns:component="clr-namespace:Component"
```

And create a separate file for the code of the component:BLSelector :

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Internals;

namespace Component
{

    public partial class BLSelector : StackLayout
    {
        #region FontSize Property
        public double FontSize
        {
            get => (double)GetValue(FontSizeProperty);
            set => SetValue(FontSizeProperty, value);
        }
        public static BindableProperty FontSizeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(FontSize), typeof(double), typeof(BLSelector), default(double), BindingMode.Default, propertyChanged: OnFontSizePropertyChanged);
        private static void OnFontSizePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var current = bindable as BLSelector;
            if (current.Content?.Children == null) return;

            foreach (var lbl in current.Content.Children.OfType<Label>()) lbl.FontSize = (double)newValue;
        }
        #endregion

        #region ItemBackGroundColor Property
        public Color ItemBackgroundColor
        {
            get => (Color)GetValue(ItemBackgroundColorProperty);
            set => SetValue(ItemBackgroundColorProperty, value);
        }
        public static BindableProperty ItemBackgroundColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemBackgroundColor), typeof(Color), typeof(BLSelector), default(Color), BindingMode.Default, propertyChanged: OnItemBackgroundColorPropertyChanged);
        private static void OnItemBackgroundColorPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var current = bindable as BLSelector;
            if (current.Content?.Children == null) return;

            // Set background of all boxview to ItemBackgroundColor
            foreach (var box in current.Content.Children.OfType<BoxView>()) box.BackgroundColor = current.ItemBackgroundColor;

            // Set background of the selected boxview to SelectedItemBackgroundColor
            if (current.SelectedItemBackgroundColor == null) return;
            ((BoxView)current.Content.Children[1 + current.Selected]).BackgroundColor = current.SelectedItemBackgroundColor;
        }
        #endregion

        #region SelectedItemBackgroundColor Property
        public Color SelectedItemBackgroundColor
        {
            get => (Color)GetValue(SelectedItemBackgroundColorProperty);
            set => SetValue(SelectedItemBackgroundColorProperty, value);
        }
        public static BindableProperty SelectedItemBackgroundColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SelectedItemBackgroundColor), typeof(Color), typeof(BLSelector), default(Color), BindingMode.Default, propertyChanged: OnSelectedItemBackgroundColorPropertyChanged);
        private static void OnSelectedItemBackgroundColorPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var current = bindable as BLSelector;
            if (current.Content?.Children == null) return;
    
            // Set background of the selected boxview to SelectedItemBackgroundColor
            ((BoxView)current.Content.Children[1 + current.Selected]).BackgroundColor = current.SelectedItemBackgroundColor;

        }
        #endregion

        #region TextColor Property
        public Color TextColor
        {
            get => (Color)GetValue(TextColorProperty);
            set => SetValue(TextColorProperty, value);
        }
        public static BindableProperty TextColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TextColor), typeof(Color), typeof(BLSelector), default(Color), BindingMode.Default, propertyChanged: OnTextColorPropertyChanged);
        private static void OnTextColorPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var current = bindable as BLSelector;
            if (current.Content?.Children == null) return;

            current.Content.Children.OfType<Label>().ForEach(c => c.TextColor = current.TextColor);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Labels Property
        public static BindableProperty LabelsProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Labels), typeof(string[]), typeof(BLSelector), null, BindingMode.Default, propertyChanged: OnLabelsPropertyChanged);
        public string[] Labels
        {
            get => (string[])GetValue(LabelsProperty);
            set => SetValue(LabelsProperty, value);
        }
        private static void OnLabelsPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var current = bindable as BLSelector;

            // Check the number of strings
            if (current.Commands != null && current.Labels.Count() != current.Commands.Count())
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Component::BLSelector - Bad number of Labels");
                throw new TargetParameterCountException();
            }

            // Updates the number of Label Controls
            current.BoxViewControls = new BoxView[current.Labels.Count()];

            // Set up the layout
            current.GridContendUpdate();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Selected Property
        public int Selected
        {
            get => (int)GetValue(SelectedProperty);
            set => SetValue(SelectedProperty, value);
        }
        public static BindableProperty SelectedProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Selected), typeof(int), typeof(BLSelector), default(int), BindingMode.Default, propertyChanged: OnSelectedPropertyChanged);
        private static void OnSelectedPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var current = bindable as BLSelector;
            if (current.Content?.Children == null) return;

            // Set background of all boxview to ItemBackgroundColor
            for (int i = 1; i < 1 + current.BoxViewControls.Count(); i++) ((BoxView)current.Content.Children[i]).BackgroundColor = current.ItemBackgroundColor;

            // Set background of the selected boxview to SelectedItemBackgroundColor
            ((BoxView)current.Content.Children[1 + current.Selected]).BackgroundColor = current.SelectedItemBackgroundColor;

            // Execute corresponding Action
            if (current.Commands != null) current.Commands[current.Selected]?.Execute(null);
        }
        #endregion


        #region Commmands Property
        public static BindableProperty CommandsProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Commands), typeof(ICommand[]), typeof(BLSelector), null, BindingMode.Default, propertyChanged: OnCommandsPropertyChanged);
            public ICommand[] Commands
            {
                get => (ICommand[])GetValue(CommandsProperty);
                set => SetValue(CommandsProperty, value);
            }
            private static void OnCommandsPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
            {
                var current = bindable as BLSelector;

                // Check the number of Commands
                if (current.Labels != null && current.Labels.Count() != current.Commands.Count())
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Component::BLSelector - Bad number of commands");
                    throw new TargetParameterCountException();
                }
            }
        #endregion

        private BoxView[] BoxViewControls;
        private Grid      Content;
        private BoxView   boxViewBackGround;
        const   int       Duration = 300;

        public  void    OnItemTapped(object obj)
        {
            Selected = BoxViewControls.IndexOf(obj);
        }

        public  void    GridContendUpdate()
        {
            Content = new Grid { Padding = 0, Margin = 0, ColumnSpacing = 0, RowSpacing = 0 };

            // Set up rows and columns of the grid
            Content.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition{ Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
            Labels.ForEach(s => {
                // Add a column for each Label
                Content.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
            });

            // Add Background - ChildIndex = 0
            boxViewBackGround = new BoxView
            {
                BackgroundColor = ItemBackgroundColor,
                CornerRadius = 10
            };
            boxViewBackGround.BindingContext = this;
            //DO NOT WORK - ATTEMPT 2
            //boxViewBackGround.SetBinding(BoxView.CornerRadiusProperty, new Binding("Height", BindingMode.Default, new HalvedConverter()));
            Content.Children.Add(boxViewBackGround, 0, Labels.Count(), 0, 1);

            // Add Background for selected item  - ChildIndew = 1 ... 1+N
            for (int i = 0; i < BoxViewControls.Count(); i++)
            {
                var boxView = new BoxView
                {
                    BackgroundColor = ItemBackgroundColor,
                    CornerRadius = 10
                };
                boxView.BindingContext = this;
                //DO NOT WORK - ATTEMPT 2
                //boxView.SetBinding(BoxView.CornerRadiusProperty, new Binding("Height", BindingMode.Default, new HalvedConverter()));

                BoxViewControls[i] = boxView;   // Memorises the control associated to the label

                // Create the Tapped Command for this boxview
                var tgr = new TapGestureRecognizer
                {
                    NumberOfTapsRequired = 1,
                    Command = new Command(OnItemTapped),
                    CommandParameter = boxView
                };
                boxView.GestureRecognizers.Add(tgr);
                Content.Children.Add(boxView, i, 0);
            }

            // Apply the SelectedItemBackgroundColor to the initially selected boxview
            ((BoxView)Content.Children[1 + Selected]).BackgroundColor = SelectedItemBackgroundColor;

            Labels.ForEach(s => {

                // Creates the Label
                Label lbl = new Label { Text = s, Padding = 0, Margin = this.Margin, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, TextColor = TextColor,
                                        FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold, FontSize = (double)GetValue(FontSizeProperty),
                                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, InputTransparent = true };

                Content.Children.Add(lbl, Labels.IndexOf(s), 0);
            });

            // If the control was already set-up (we are on an update) then remove the actual content to replace/update it
            if (Children.Count() > 0) Children.RemoveAt(0);
            
            // Add the (new/updated) content
            Children.Add(Content);
        }

        //DO NOT WORK - ATTEMPT 1
        protected override void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            if (propertyName == nameof(Height))
            {
                foreach (var box in Content.Children.OfType<BoxView>())
                {
                    box.CornerRadius = this.Height / 2;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public class HalvedConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (double)value / 2.0F;
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("HalvedConverter - Only one way bindings are supported with this converter");
            throw new NotSupportedException("HalvedConverter - Only one way bindings are supported with this converter");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `But correctly as soon as you click once on an item.`  After deploying it on my Android device, even clicking on it didn't work either.

Comment: Strange, I commit an update with more comments and debug info. For me the first control is working propermy because I set the Corner radius in the XAML, but the second is NOT working because the corner raidus is set dynamically at the display time.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT, I found a way to make it working ... but i don' know why ... I just replace the boxviews (which acts as background for the label items) by frames and now it works. Did you have an idea Why ?????